# Openlayers 3 different projection Geojson view

Tags: openlayers, geojson

My map projection is `EPSG:3857`. And I want to show a GeoJSON data which has `EPSG:4326` projection.

```
            var source = new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'http://localhost:15485/api/locations',
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            });                
            var locationsGeojsonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: source,
                projection: 'EPSG:3857'
            });
```

Locations are getting from url but does not apper on map. Openlayers does not automatically convert URL data.

if I use ajax call and add features manually it appears on map.

```
            $http({method: "GET", url: "http://localhost:15485/api/locations"}).then(function (response) {
                angular.forEach(response.data, function (item) {

                    var feature = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeature(item,{
                        dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                        featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                    });

                    source.addFeature(feature);
                })
            });
```

Comment: It would help to clarify what exactly the question is here, but I believe you have highlighted the primary issue here and that's the fact that ol.source.Vector() won't automatically reproject the data for you. You need to use the old.format.GeoJSON().readFeature() to project and display, as you have demonstrated.